Form Does not take up entire space in Sheet
I am using a Form in a Sheet. I want the form to take up the entire width and height of the sheet.
Here is what I have:
Form View:
import SwiftUI

struct FormView: View {
  @State var title: String = ""

  var body: some View {
    Form {
       Text("Title").multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
        .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
        .padding([.leading])
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        TextField("", text: $title).textInput()
          .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
          .padding([.leading, .trailing])
          .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)       
            
           
    }.ignoresSafeArea(.all)
  }

}


The FormView is used in a sheet like this:
struct CreateItemButton: View {
    
    @State var shouldPresentSheet = false
    
    
    var body: some View {
       Button("Raise Issue", action: {
                shouldPresentSheet = true
       }).sheet(isPresented: $shouldPresentSheet, content: {
                FormView()
            })
    }
    
    
}

This gets me this (notice the edges of the form don't go all the way to the edges of the sheet)

I need the Form to take up all the space inside the sheet (up to the edges)

Try .formStyle(.columns)

@BenzyNeez That did the trick. For others in the future, if you use a Picker the format gets messed up. If you put it in an VStack It will work nicely.
